# Change panel starting point

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, autoscroll

In my program i have a panel of 1000 by 1500 pixels, in that panel is a panel of 4000 by 10000 pixels which I can scroll through. Now this panel starts like in the left (example in the picture) but i was wondering if I could make it start like in the right example. And is it possible to change the 0,0 point of the Panel (picture in the link)

[image: Panel i got and panel i want]

Im using a derived Panel

```
class BufferedPanel : Panel
    {
        public BufferedPanel()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you just want to change the initial scroll position? Or if it's not autoscroll, do you mean you just want to set the location of the internal panel to something like (0, -1250)?

Comment: it is autoscroll, and i want to do just that, but is it also possible to set, like (0, 1250) as the (0,0) point ?

Comment: You should set the value of `outerPanel.AutoScrollPosition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the initial scroll position for the outer auto-scroll panel. To do so you can set [`AutoScrollPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the outer panel. You should do it after the form is shown:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 1250);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, what kind of eventhandler do i need to add for the panel in the desinger class tho?

Comment: Overriding `OnShown` method of `Form` would be enough. If you don't like to override `OnShown` method of the `Form`, handle `Shown` event of the form.

Comment: is there a way to call this functionmore often while running, like when a trackbar(using it for zoom) is released. i got an eventhandler function for that

Comment: Yes, you can call it at anytime after showing the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Location property of your new Panel.

```
Panel.Location = New Point(OriginalPanel.Width/2 - Panel.Size.Width/2, OriginalPanel.Height/2 - Panel.Size.Height/2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this makes it impossible for me to scroll to the top part of the panel. I can see the scrollbar doubling in size and then i cant scroll to the line in the top anymore

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this to the panel constructor:

```
this.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
```

Comment: this removes the vertical scrollbar on the panel, im setting the scrollbar like this:this.Panel.AutoScroll = true;

Comment: try to add this.AutoScroll = true; in the same place when you put this.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;

Comment: i need to anchor the large panel right? but i have set AutoScroll = true on the smaller panel in which the large panel sits, otherwise it didnt work

Comment: which panel do you need to have scrollable, outer or inner ?

Comment: the large panel inside the smaller panel needs to be scrollable, it only works when i set autoscroll true on the small panel